# How can I get any expression in C# as string?

Tags: .net, keyword, string-literals

In many cases one needs the name of an expression, parameter, statement, etc. For example:

```
public abstract void Log(string methodName, string parameterName, string message);

public void FooMethod(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.Log("FooMethod", "value", "The value must be whatever...");
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    }

    if (value.Length < 5)
    {
        this.Log("FooMethod", "value.Length", "The value length must be whatever...");
        throw new ArgumentException("value");
    }
}
```

Is there any way of getting these string literals automatically like for example with a keyword that can be used like `typeof(string)`?
Or is there a simple and performant approach based on reflection?

I'm not looking for a way to check and log this parameter (which is actually only an example). I'm looking for a method to get part of the code as `string`.

The following would be more accurate, could be checked by the compiler and would also be considered when refactoring the code:

```
public void FooMethod(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        this.Log(literal(this.FooMethod), literal(value), "The parameter '" + literal(value) + "' must be whatever...");
        throw new ArgumentNullException(literal(value));            
    }

    if (value.Length < 5)
    {
        this.Log(literal(this.FooMethod), literal(value.Length), "The value length must be whatever...");
        throw new ArgumentException(literal(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second sample is bogus. No code will execute after a `throw`.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I changed the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create static methods like this for all possible types. Below is for method name.

```
public static string GetString(Action obj)
{
    return obj.Method.Name;
}

public static string GetString(Delegate obj )
{
    return obj.Method.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need [StackTrace.GetFrame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe.aspx). This method will get you the required StackFrame object from which you can find this information.

Check out the following code sample

```
StackFrame fr = new StackFrame(1,true);
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(fr);
this.Log.WriteEntry(fr.GetMethod().Name,
                    fr.GetMethod().GetParameters()[0].Name,
                    "The value must be whatever...");
```

By the way, in your second code example the Log method calls will never execute because an exception is throw before the calls. No code in a method will execute after an exception is thrown except for code in a `finally` block. See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately getting the stackframe can take several µs or even ms and this exceeds the expected duration by several orders of magnitutude!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your goal is. If you're looking to get the runtime values [Martin Doms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7158599/how-can-i-get-any-expression-in-c-as-string/7158689#7158689) answer might be the solution. If you wish to be able to link say ArgumentNullException to a specific argument name, and ensure that if you change the name you can use refactoring you can do something like this:

```
 public static void NotNull<T>(Expression<Func<IEnumerable<T>>> exp)
        {
            var expBody = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
                T value = exp.Compile().Invoke();
                if (value == null){
                    string memberName;
                    if (expBody != null){
                        memberName = expBody.Member.Name;
                    } else{
                        memberName = "member";
                    }
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(memberName, memberName + " cannot be null");
                }
        }
```

you can then use it like so:

```
public void Method(string value){
  Ensure.NotNull(()=>value);
}
```

it will check if the value is null and format an appropriate message to the ArgumentNullException if value is null.
How ever if you are on .NET 4.0 I'd suggest using contracts for this stuff instead. Not that it actually solves your particular needs here but argument checking using Contracts has a lot of benefits when it comes to documentation and static analysis compared to doing it "the old fashionged way"

Comment: Actually I'm not looking for a solution to check the value, which can already be done with code contracts. I'm looking for a way to get a part of the code as string.

Comment: @matthias: In you example you're checking the value so and then if the value is X using properties of the code that let you there I thought that was your usage scenario. That's what the above code snippet does. You can't get the names using contracts, you can using expressions. But as I said it depends on when you won't them. If you want run time values go for stackframe, if you wish to inspect an expression you need to represent it as an expression tree